# Mongo DB not working in Ubuntu0.16.04.2

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I just installed mongodb by following the instructions at [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04).

When I try to start mongodb using command

```
  sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

it goes to next command line and after that i run the command

```
 sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

I got the following message

```
   mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-08-13 16:37:29 IST; 2min 50s ago
   Process: 10572 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
   Main PID: 10572 (code=exited, status=14)
   Aug 13 16:37:28 nagainfo-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
   Aug 13 16:37:29 nagainfo-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
   Aug 13 16:37:29 nagainfo-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
   Aug 13 16:37:29 nagainfo-Lenovo-G50-70 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Please help me to resolve this. I have tried many things like giving permission to log and lib fies. But nothing work for me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: does it shows any `mongo` version when you check

Comment: this is an installation guide for ubuntu by mongodb.org follow its steps
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/
and if mongodb already installed and, if you want to uninstall those packages use http://askubuntu.com/questions/147135/how-can-i-uninstall-mongodb-and-reinstall-the-latest-version it shows everything.

Comment: I have almost exactly the same error message with lubuntu 16.04.   Yes, there are plenty of 'guides' out there, mostly full of misinformation.  I have nearly given up on this until developers can come up with some sane installation policies. Such as consistent database folder path, consistent startup commands that work with systemd/systemctl, whatever, stuff that normal webdev's don't want to care about.